# Windows.​Security.​Credentials.Password​Vaultの詳細と安全性について

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwp

UWPでアプリを開発しています。ユーザー名・パスワードなどの資格情報を保存する方法として、[Windows.​Security.​Credentials.Password​Vault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault)の存在を知りました。しかしながら、比較的新しい機能なのか情報が少なく、どういった性格のものであるのか述べた文書を見つけられませんでした。

### 質問

- Q1: 前述したリンク先リファレンスには

  > Apps and services don't have access to credentials associated with other apps or services.

  との記述がありますが、ここでの`Apps`は開発しているアプリケーションそれぞれ1つを指すものと考えてよろしいのでしょうか（言い換えると、Appsの同一性は何を基準にしているのでしょうか）？
- Q2: このAPIによって保存される資格情報はどこに、どのような状態で格納されますか。それが（よっぽどのことをしない限り）このAPI以外を用いてアクセスできないならば、確かに安全かと思われます。

以上の点についてご回答をいただきたく存じます。または、こうした内容を述べた文書をご存知でしたら、日本語・英語を問いませんのでお教えください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Windowsには[Credential Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374792(v=vs.85).aspx)という資格情報を保存する機能が提供されています。Internet ExplorerやEdge、Google ChromeなどがWebのパスワードなどを保存するだけでなく、Skypeなど対応しているアプリケーションも資格情報を保存する際に使用しています。これらはコントロールパネルの「資格情報マネージャー」から確認することができますが、一部表示されないものもあります。
`Password​Vault`もこれらを扱うためにクラスかと。[資格情報保管ボックス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker)も参照ください。